# Does the set of points $\{\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{x}=(\mathbf{v}^H\mathbf{R}\mathbf{v})\mathbf{v}\}$ represent a multidimensional ellipse?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

Given a unit-length column vector $\mathbf{v}$, does the set of points given by the length-scaled vector

$\{\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{x} = (\mathbf{v}^H\mathbf{R}\mathbf{v})\mathbf{v}\}$

represent a multidimensional ellipse? I guess it does since the projection of $\mathbf{x}$ onto the eigenvector $\mathbf{v}_k$ of $\mathbf{R}$ is its eigenvalue $\lambda_k$.

But how to prove it?

Comment: It is not really clear. What you can say is something like : the set of points $\{v \vert v^\top R v \leq 1 \}$ forms an $R$-norm ball, which is an ellipsoid.

Comment: @VanBaffo Thank you. I modified the question.

Comment: What properties does $R$ have?

Comment: $R$ is an Hermittian, nonnegative definite,toeplitz matrix.

Comment: The general equation for an ellipsoid is $\frac{z_1^2}{a_1^2} + \frac{z_2^2}{a_2^2} + … + \frac{z_n^2}{a_n^2} = r^2$. See if you can rewrite your set in this form. Hint: Perform a change of basis.

Comment: @Hyperplane I have tried but failed. I change the basis to the eigenvectors of $R$, but it doesn't simplify to the ellipsoid form you give. Hope you can help.

Comment: @ecook Have you tried plotting some example for $n=2$ to check if it is actually an ellipse?

Comment: @Hyperplane ah, it is not! It is a peanut-shaped closed surface, both for $n=2$ and $n=3$. Here comes another question: does the point set form a closed surface, for the general case $n>3$?